# BackboneJS event bindings non English content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js

This is the situation, which seems to me very weird...

This is the code piece.

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.login',
    events: {
        'click #clickMe': 'clickMe',
    },

    clickMe: function (e) {
       console.log('Clicked!')
    }
});
```

Where '.login' is a parent container and the '#clickMe' is a button in it

The website is multilangual.. and the code works (i.e prints "Clicked" in console) fine, when swiching the language(with PHP) to other language (i.e Switzerland, which changes all the textes), the click event simply not fire, no errors.. nothing, it just wont consolelog the text

Ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that somehow id changes from `clickMe` to something else?

Comment: Please post the html that comes from the server for the Swiss (or any non-English) version

Comment: No, ID is always same,

this is the html code, it is the same for both languages

`<section class="login">
    <span class="error"></span>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="name">
        </div>
        <a id="clickMe" href="javascript:;">LOGIN</a>
    </form>
</section>`

Comment: Only thing is changed there is lables and textes, for example in other langauge the value of <a> will be

`<a id="clickMe" href="javascript:;">PRIHLÁSENIE</a>`

can this break the binding?

Comment: lang switching come dynamically or with postback and page reloading?

Comment: How are you loading your Backbone JavaScript? External JS (`<script src=...></script>`) or inline (`<script>...code...</script>`)? Where is the `<script></script>` loaded in your document? In the `<head>`, at the top of the `<body>`, bottom? Are you using `$(document).ready()`? Btw, to let me know that you replied use my username with the @-sign (@Seebiscuit) somewhere in your comment.

Comment: Can you please 1. ensure `view` is instantiated in your "non-english" site by implementing `initialize(){ var test = 1; }` holding in a breakpoint at `test` and 2. when stopping at that break point check if the element with the class `.login` and `#clickMe` really do exist. Ensure your code only runs on document load (`$.ready()`)